# Boxed lottery tickets, rencontres numbers and number of degree-$n$ permutations of order exactly $d$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, lotteries

This is a question that I encountered at work that I am trying to get a deeper understanding of.

We sell tickets in a lottery where you guess $4$ numbers out of range of $36$ (the range is irrelevant to this problem) in an order. Four numbers are drawn. If your first guessed number matches the first drawn number it is considered a match, likewise for the second, third and fourth draws. You get different prizes for how many numbers you get matched.  Matching all four gets you an $S4$ prize, matching three gets you an $S3$ prize and so on.

However we also offer a "boxed" ticket, which is equivalent to buying all $24$ permutations of the $4$ numbers you selected. You can determine how many prizes of each class you will win for the count of matching numbers from this table:
$$\begin{array}{ |c | c | c | c | c | } \hline
\text{Matching Numbers} & S4 & S3 & S2 & S1 \\
4 & 1 & 0 & 6 & 8 \\
3 & 0 & 1 & 3 & 9 \\
2 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 8 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 6 \\
\hline
\end{array} $$
Now the "$4$" matching row is the number of permutations of $4$ with $4$, $3$, $2$, $1$ fixed points, i.e. the rencontres numbers $n=4$. This naturally falls out of the problem description and I understand this.

By use of the OEIS database I was able to work out that $3$ matching number row corresponds to number of degree-$n$ permutations of order exactly $2$. Row 2 matching number row corresponds to number of degree-$n$ permutations of order exactly $3$.

I am unsure if this is a genuine correspondence or if it is a coincidence. I am wondering if there is a general way to generate this table, for example for a lottery with n selected numbers.

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something. With $3$ matching numbers, how can we get an $S2$ prize? If two numbers are in the correct position, the third must also be in the correct position.

Comment: @robjohn   for example you select $\{1, 2, 3, 5\}$ but "1,2,3,4" is drawn. So you get prizes for "1,2,5,3", "1,5,3,2" and "5,2,3,1".

Comment: @AlexFrancisco The entries that satisfy $D{4,1}$ that is all the permutations of degree 4 with a single fixed point are "1,3,4,2", "1,4,2,3", "3, 2, 4, 1", "4, 2, 1, 3", "2, 4, 3, 1", "4, 1, 3, 2", "2, 3, 1, 4", "3,  1, 2, 4" that's 8 by my count. what one am I missing?

Comment: @QthePlatypus My mistake.

Comment: Can we assume that no one buys a box ticket with duplicate guesses, like "1, 2, 3, 3"? Because that breaks down the table. Can we similarly assume the 4 numbers drawn are distinct?

Comment: Duplicate guesses are impossble and the numbers are drawn without replacement so are distinct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Building  on the  work  by @AlexFrancisco  in  clarifying the  problem
definition, establishing a recurrence  and providing examples it would
seem that we have the closed form

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{m\choose k} \sum_{q=0}^{m-k} {m-k\choose q} (-1)^q (n-k-q)!.}$$

This is the number of prizes of  class $k$ with $m$ matches from among
$n$ total. With this formula we  first select the $k$ matches from the
$m$ available ones and combine  them with a generalized derangement of
the rest, which we compute by inclusion-exclusion.

For the PIE argument we have  that the nodes $Q$ of the underlying
poset represent subsets  $Q\subseteq R$ of the set  of potential fixed
points $R$  of cardinality $m-k$  that are  required not to  be fixed.
The permutations  represented at  $Q$ have the  elements of  $Q$ being
fixed  in addition  to  the  $k$, plus  possibly  more.  This set  has
cardinality  $(n-k-|Q|)!.$  We  ask  about   the  total  weight  of  a
permutation of the $n-k$ remaining elements after the $k$ fixed points
have  been chosen,  where the  weights  at $Q$  are $(-1)^{|Q|}$.   An
admissible permutation has none of the elements of $R$ being fixed and
hence    is   only    included    in    $Q=\emptyset$   with    weight
$(-1)^{|\emptyset|} =  1.$ A  permutation with exactly  $P\subseteq R$
fixed points  in addition to  the $k$ where $P\ne\emptyset$  and hence
$|P|\ge 1$ is included at all nodes $Q\subseteq P,$ for a total weight
of

$$\sum_{Q\subseteq P} (-1)^{|Q|}
= \sum_{q=0}^{|P|} {|P|\choose q} (-1)^q = 0.$$

The total  weight of a permutation  where none of the  elements of $R$
are fixed is  one, and zero otherwise.  We conclude  that the sum term
of  the proposed  formula  counts exactly  those  permutations of  the
remaining $n-k$ elements  where none of the $m-k$ elements  of $R$ are
fixed.

Comment: Inclusion-exclusion principle! Why did I forget that?! This makes everything simple now.

Answer (score 4):

Here a general formula for the table will be given.

> **Step 1:** Given distinct $a_1, a_2, \cdots$ and $b_1, b_2, \cdots$, define $A_n = \{a_1, \cdots, a_n\}$ and $B_n = \{b_1, \cdots, b_n\}$ for $n \geqslant 0$, and$$
> \mathscr{F}_{m, n} = \{φ: A_m → A_m \cup B_n \mid φ \text{ is injective},\ φ(x) ≠ x,\ \forall x \in A_m\},\\
> f(m, n) = |\mathscr{F}_{m, n}|,
> $$
>   where $m, n \geqslant 0$. Then for $n \geqslant 0$,$$
> f(0, n) = 1, \quad f(1, n) = n,\\
> f(m, n) = (m + n - 1)f(m - 1, n) + (m - 1)f(m - 2, n). \quad (m \geqslant 2)
> $$

*Proof:* Obviously $f(0, n) = 1$. For $m = 1$, since $φ(a_1) \in B_n$, then $f(1, n) = n$. Now consider $m \geqslant 2$.

If $φ(a_1) \in B_n$, then intuitively$$
φ|_{A_m \setminus \{a_1\}}: A_m \setminus \{a_1\} \longrightarrow (A_m \setminus \{a_1\}) \cup \bigl( (B_n \setminus \{φ(a_1)\}) \cup \{a_1\} \bigr)
$$
corresponds to a mapping in $\mathscr{F}_{m - 1, n}$ and thus$$
|\{φ \in \mathscr{F}_{m, n} \mid φ(a_1) \in B_n\}| = n f(m - 1, n). \tag{1}
$$
If $φ(a_1) = a_i$ and $φ(a_i) = a_1$, then intuitively$$
φ|_{A_m \setminus \{a_1, a_i\}}: A_m \setminus \{a_1, a_i\} \longrightarrow (A_m \setminus \{a_1, a_i\}) \cup B_n
$$
corresponds to a mapping in $\mathscr{F}_{m - 2, n}$. If $φ(a_1) = a_i$ but $φ(a_i) ≠ a_1$, then intuitively$$
φ|_{A_m \setminus \{a_1\}}: (A_m \setminus \{a_1, a_i\}) \cup \{a_i\} \longrightarrow \bigl( (A_m \setminus \{a_1, a_i\}) \cup \{a_1\} \bigr) \cup B_n
$$
corresponds to a mapping in $\mathscr{F}_{m - 1, n}$. Thus$$
|\{φ \in \mathscr{F}_{m, n} \mid φ(a_1) \in A_m\}| = (m - 1) (f(m - 1, n) + f(m - 2, n)). \tag{2}
$$
Combining (1) and (2) yields$$
f(m, n) = (m + n - 1)f(m - 1, n) + (m - 1)f(m - 2, n).
$$
The rest of this proof focuses on rigorously proving (1) since (2) can be proved analogously.

By symmetry,$$
|\{φ \in \mathscr{F}_{m, n} \mid φ(a_1) \in B_n\}| = n·|\{φ \in \mathscr{F}_{m, n} \mid φ(a_1) = b_1\}|.
$$
On the one hand, for $φ \in \mathscr{F}_{m, n}$ such that $φ(a_1) = b_1$, define $ψ: A_{m - 1} → A_{m - 1} \cup B_n$ as$$
ψ(x) = \begin{cases}
b_1; & x = a_i,\ φ(a_{i + 1}) = a_1\\
a_j; & x = a_i,\ φ(a_{i + 1}) = a_{j + 1}\\
b_j; & x = a_i,\ φ(a_{i + 1}) = b_j
\end{cases},
$$
then $ψ \in \mathscr{F}_{m - 1, n}$. Note that this defines an injective mapping from $\{φ \in \mathscr{F}_{m, n} \mid φ(a_1) = b_1\}$ to $\mathscr{F}_{m - 1, n}$, thus$$
|\{φ \in \mathscr{F}_{m, n} \mid φ(a_1) = b_1\}| \leqslant f(m - 1, n).
$$
On the other hand, for $ψ \in \mathscr{F}_{m - 1, n}$, define $φ: A_m → A_m \cup B_n$ as$$
φ(x) = \begin{cases}
b_1; & x = a_1\\
a_{j + 1}; & x = a_{i + 1},\ ψ(a_i) = a_j\\
a_1; & x = a_{i + 1},\ ψ(a_i) = b_1\\
b_{j + 1}; & x = a_{i + 1},\ ψ(a_i) = b_{j + 1}
\end{cases},
$$
then $φ \in \mathscr{F}_{m, n}$ and $φ(a_1) = b_1$. Note that this is an injective mapping from $\mathscr{F}_{m - 1, n}$ to $\{φ \in \mathscr{F}_{m, n} \mid φ(a_1) = b_1\}$, thus$$
f(m - 1, n) \leqslant |\{φ \in \mathscr{F}_{m, n} \mid φ(a_1) = b_1\}|.
$$
Therefore (1) holds.

> **Step 2:** Given distinct $a_1, a_2, \cdots$, $b_1, b_2, \cdots$, and $c_1, c_2, \cdots$, define $A_n = \{a_1, \cdots, a_n\}$, $B_n = \{b_1, \cdots, b_n\}$, $C_n = \{c_1, \cdots, c_n\}$ for $n \geqslant 0$, and$$
> \mathscr{G}_{k, m, n} = \{φ: A_m \cup B_{n - m} → A_m \cup C_{n - m} \mid φ \text{ is injective with exactly } k \text{ fixed points}\},\\
> g(k, m, n) = |\mathscr{G}_{k, m, n}|,
> $$
>   where $k \leqslant m \leqslant n$. Then$$
> g(k, m, n) = (n - m)!\, C(m, k) f(m - k, n - m).
> $$
>   (Note that $g(k, m, n)$ is the number of prizes of class $k$ if there are $m$ matching numbers out of $n$ in total.)

*Proof:* There are $C(m, k)$ ways to select $k$ fixed points from $A_m$, then $f(m - k, n - m)$ ways to select the images of the rest $m - k$ elements of $A_m$, and then $(n - m)!$ ways to select the images of elements in $B_{n - m}$. Thus$$
g(k, m, n) = (n - m)!\, C(m, k) f(m - k, n - m).
$$

Comment: Is $C\left(m,k\right) = \dbinom{m}{k}$ ?

Comment: @darijgrinberg Yes.

Comment: This looks very good.  Though I'm still curious why there is the correspondence with the permutation group count.